# Possible to replicate economist.com's debate section in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, customization

We're building an online magazine with a debate section similar to economist.com/debate. Is it possible to do it in wordpress with existing plugins?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Despite the downvotes – I think this is an interesting question.

Answer (score 3):

That section looks extremely feature-rich and very custom. The possibility of just installing several plugins and getting something like that is pretty much zero (in my opinion).

WordPress does have building blocks for such functionality:

- posts and custom post types for information;
- comments for discussion;
- scheduling functionality and calendar-related plugins;
- plugins for relationships between information;
- plugins for voting;
- plugins for graphs.

However to put all of that together in single coherent experience would definitely take considerable development effor.